# Prevent column-count spliting only one item in container

Tags: css

I have a listing container with n items, which I split in two columns using `column-count`.

In some cases there can be only one item in the listing.

I'm using the following css:

http://jsfiddle.net/ny3Rc/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
        The first problem is how the browser should handle one or more extra lines of content if the amount of content cannot fill up each column equally. In my opinion, the extra content should come at the bottom of the first columns, so that columns further to the right are never longer than columns further to the left. This is pretty standard practice in print design, and having it any other way just looks really strange. At least to me. Take a look and you decide
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.list {-moz-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; column-count: 2;}
.list-item {}
```

How can I prevent `column-count` spliting my list-item in two columns **when there is only one item on the list**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add...

```
display: -webkit-inline-box;
```

to list-item.

Comment: Was looking for firefox equivalent too - checking here http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/moz-inline-box - and found out that this is actually the equivalent of **inline-block**. So using inline-block actually solves this issue in all browsers

Comment: Nice, I'm glad the propety works without the vendor specific prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Hello :) I had a `ul` with dynamically added `li` items with a border. When there were many items everything was ok, but with one item border at the bottom displayed on the second column. I think the problem was that by default a `li` item's display property is `list-item`. I solved the problem with this code:

```
.list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hey Alexander, you can actually answer your own question, rather than add your solution to your actual question, and then mark the answer as solved.